# How can i display string instead of image in UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Interface is define like this

```
@interface IGLDemoCustomView : UIView
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
@end
```

While Implementation file look like this

```
  @interface IGLDemoCustomView ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel
    @end

    @implementation IGLDemoCustomView

    - (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            [self commonInit];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) {
            [self commonInit];
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)commonInit
    {
        [self initView];
    }

   - (void)initView
{
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.59 blue:0.69 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.alpha = 0.8;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    self.imageView = imageView;
    UILabel *titleLabel;
    self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    titleLabel.center = self.center; // set proper frame for label
    [self addSubview:titleLabel];
}
    - (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
    {
        _image = image;
        self.imageView.image = image;
    }

   - (void)setString:(NSString *)title
{
    self.title=title;
    self.titleLabel.text = title;
}
    - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        [super setFrame:frame];
        self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2.0;
    }

    @end
```

When i select image from the drop down menu it shows in the menu, but when i select any text from the drop down menu it doesnt show in the drop down list view.

Any clue will be highly appreciated.
Calling and setting string in the view

```
 IGLDropDownItem *menuButton = strongSelf.dropDownMenu.menuButton;
        IGLDemoCustomView *buttonView = (IGLDemoCustomView*)menuButton.customView;
        buttonView.title = device.name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a frame for the label

```
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    self.titleLabel.frame = self.bounds;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.height / 2.0;
}
```

If you are expecting the text to wrap, you'll need to set the `lineBreakMode` and set `numberOfLines` to 0

Answer (score 0):

Like you are having `UIImageView` you need to have a `UILabel` inside your `UIView` too.

```
@interface IGLDemoCustomView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel;

@end

- (void)initView
{
  self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.18 green:0.59 blue:0.69 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
  self.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
  self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.alpha = 0.8;

  UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
  imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
  [self addSubview:imageView];
  self.imageView = imageView;

  self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  titleLabel.center = self.center; // set proper frame for label
  [self addSubview:titleLabel]
}
```

And in `setString`

```
- (void)setString:(NSString *)title
{
  self.title=title;
  self.titleLabel.text = title;
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have done the changes but still doesnt work. I have edited the code above, and describe how am i calling it as well. Kindly help in that regards